# Combine two pandas dataframes with two conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are two pandas dataframes I have which I would like to combine with checking of two conditionals.

Dataframe1:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['Z085', '2020-08', 1.33], ['Z086', '2020-08', 1.83], ['Z086', '2020-09', 1.39]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SN', 'Date', 'Value'])
```

[image]

Dataframe2:

```
data = [['Z085', '2020-08', 0.34], ['Z085', '2020-09', 0.83], ['Z086', '2020-09', 0.29]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['SN', 'Date', 'ValueX']) 
df2
```

[image]

I would like to merge or append or join them in order to get the folowing dataframe:
The values ("Value" and "ValueX") are being add if both "SN" and "Date" are equal.

[image]

I am not sure, if a new dataframe is required or to map the df2 to the df1.

This is what i have tried:

```
df1['ValueX'] = df1[('Date', 'SN')].map(df2_mean.set_index('Date', 'SN')['ValueX'])
```

With one conditional (for example: Date) it works ok, but i am not able to set up two conditionals.

Comment: This is simply a `merge()` operation. Don't call the columns "conditionals", just say "merge on the columns SN, Date". Read: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: In your example output, the sort-order is different to what you get with `merge(..., sort=False)` Does it matter? What sort-order (if any) do you want on your output: `['SN','Date']` don't-care, or what? Please edit into your question. In general, we should avoid unnecessary sorting by key(s) on large data, it's wasteful and non-scaleable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**:

```
df_new = df1.merge(df2, on=['SN','Date'],how='outer', sort=True)
print(df_new)
```

**Method 2 : [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)**:

```
df_new = df1.join(df2.set_index(['SN','Date']), on=['SN','Date'],how='outer', sort=True)
print(df_new)
```

In this case, one more possible way would be to use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1.set_index(['SN','Date']),df2.set_index(['SN','Date'])],axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Output in either case**:

```
     SN     Date  Value  ValueX
0  Z085  2020-08   1.33    0.34
3  Z085  2020-09    NaN    0.83
1  Z086  2020-08   1.83     NaN
2  Z086  2020-09   1.39    0.29
```

Comment: **You don't need the `.sort_values('SN')`** at the end, just `.merge(..., sort=False)` per my answer. As long as both input dataframes were already sorted in increasing SN, no need to scramble them then re-sort them; just inefficient.

Comment: @smci Thanks for the input. However, I added `.sort_values('SN')` to match the output format of original post. Nothing else!  Also, `sort=False` is the default behavior. `sort=False` doesn't give the same output as the OP wants. I think you meant `sort=True`. In any case, I have updated my answer. **Can I get my downvote removed please?**

Comment: Grayrigel: hmm, it's unclear if the OP cares about sort-order and if so what order they want to impose. Let's wait for them to respond. I didnt realize that was the intent of your multiple alternatives, suggest you add that as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a `merge()` operation. Don't call the columns "conditionals", just say "merge on the columns SN, Date".

However pandas (v1.1.4) has a bug (its default is to use reversed i.e.  'ascending') key order when doing the sort) so you can't rely on it; note below it gets sorted by 'Date' then 'SN', i.e. wrong-way-around:

```
>>> dfnew_bad = df1.merge(df2, on=['SN','Date'], how='outer')

     SN     Date  Value  ValueX
0  Z085  2020-08   1.33    0.34
1  Z086  2020-08   1.83     NaN
2  Z086  2020-09   1.39    0.29
3  Z085  2020-09    NaN    0.83
```

So in your case to get the correct **order by SN then Date**:

```
dfnew_good = df1.merge(df2, on=['SN','Date'], how='outer', sort=False).sort_values(['SN', 'Date'])
     SN     Date  Value  ValueX
0  Z085  2020-08   1.33    0.34
3  Z085  2020-09    NaN    0.83
1  Z086  2020-08   1.83     NaN
2  Z086  2020-09   1.39    0.29
```

Note that there's a flag [`.sort_values(ascending=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) but not [`pd.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)
You could also workaround by doing `pd.merge(..., sort=False)` then `dfnew_workaround.sort_index(..., inplace=True)`

Comment: I am a bit confused by second part of your answer. `sort=False` followed by `sort_values`, why not just `sort=True`.

Comment: @Grayrigel: because pandas 1.1.x still has a bug and doesn't do the sort right when the key is compound: it sorts on `Date` then `SN`, i.e. it reverses the key order.